# Given the area of a segment of the unit circle, find the central angle

Tags: trigonometry

> If a segment of the unit circle has area $\pi/4$, then how do you determine the central angle?

In the figure, $|\overline{OA}| = 1$, and the area of segment $APB$ is $\pi/4 = 0.78539\ldots$.
[image]

Comment: Area of a sector = $\pi \cdot r^2 \cdot \frac{\text{angle of sector}}{2\pi}$

Comment: There is a difference between a *segment* and a *sector*. Which do you mean?

Comment: Area of Segment

Comment: John, thanks for replying.  I added a picture that shows what I am trying to do.  I hope the picture shows.  I am not sure how to add a picture - I'm new to this site.

Comment: Deepak, I have added a picture of the problem, Hope it helps

Comment: Can Newton's Method be used to determine the point 'M'?

Comment: With the help of two mathematicians, they answered the question.  I wrote up two pdf files.  Can they be loaded up? How